# ¿Como descargar un excel en django con un boton?

Tags: python, django

Hola quiero hacer un boton que descargue un archivo excel en django que esta en el servidor en la carpeta de static

mi views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from . import urls
from django.http import HttpResponse
from wsgiref.util import FileWrapper

from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
def descargarArchiv(request):
    filename = r'nombre'



    content = FileWrapper(filename)
    response = HttpResponse(content, content_type='application/pdf')
    response['Content-Length'] = os.path.getsize(filename)
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s' % 'NOOOO.jpg'
   return response
```

En el template tengo así

```
<input type="button" value="Download" onclick="window.open('descargarPlanDeEstudios')">
```

y mis urls.py

```
path('descargarPlanDeEstudios', views.descargarArchiv)
```

pero solo me abre una pagina en blanco

Comment: Saludos podrias agregar la url directamente mediante un hipervinculo asi:"<a href="/url/a/mi/excel">Descargar Plan</a>"

Comment: Buen día: Ya lo hiciste?

Comment: Si ya lo solucione.